# How to sort a list of lists and and to keep only the maximal 2nd element of each of the 1st elements?

Tags: python, list, numpy, sorting

Let's say that I have some list:

```
lst = [[2,6],[1,4],[0,1],[1,1],[2,3],[0,2]]
```

I want to sort **lst** by the first element and for each sublist keep the one with the maximal second element when grouped by the first element.

So the results will be:

```
results
>>> [[0,2],[1,4],[2,6]]
```

Can someone kindly help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `np.maximum.reduceat`:

```
import numpy as np
lst = np.array([[2,6],[1,4],[0,1],[1,1],[2,3],[0,2]])
lst = lst[np.argsort(lst[:,0])] #sorting lst by first row
u, idx = np.unique(lst[:,0], return_index = True) 
print(np.c_[u, np.maximum.reduceat(lst[:,1], idx)])
```

At first array should be sorted. Then you need to get indices that splits array into groups: `idx = [0, 2, 4]` and corresponding values of first column `u = [0, 1, 2]`. Finally, use `np.maximum.reduceat` in order to get maximum values of groups that starts at indices `idx` specified and display it concatenated rightwise to `u`.

***Remark:*** I used `numpy` here, a widely used library that allows to push looping into C level which is much faster. Purely pythonic solutions are worth attention too.

***Bonus:*** This is actually a one liner using a `numpy_indexed` library (not so widely used) dedicated for groupby operations of arrays:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
import numpy as np
np.transpose(npi.group_by(lst[:, 0]).max(lst[:, 1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you just have 'pairs' like this (e.g. always 2 ints per sublist with the same 1st value and a 2nd value), it's very simple:

```
>>> lst = [[2,6],[1,4],[0,1],[1,1],[2,3],[0,2]]
>>> sorted(lst)[1::2]
[[0, 2], [1, 4], [2, 6]]
```

Sorting the list by default sorts on the 1st and then 2nd value of each sublist, then just slice the resulting list to take every other item

Comment: When slicing, you are also assuming there are exactly two sublists per different first value, but you did not state that assumption.

Comment: @Stef Yes exactly, that's also what i meant by 'pairs' but i didn't explain it well

Comment: @Chris_Rands It's phrased a bit oddly, but it was clear to me what you meant. And I found it a reasonable assumption (that's why I gave the first upvote), since the example data would be bad if it weren't the case, and since there are applications that do that, for example algorithms that store `(object_id, x_coordinate)` pairs, one pair for "entering" the object (with its left coordinate) and one for "leaving" the object with its right coordinate. All that said, applying a `dict` as in my answer isn't that much more work and makes it more general :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sort the list, group the elements by first item and then keep the max by second item in each group

```
import itertools as it
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [[2,6],[1,4],[0,1],[1,1],[2,3],[0,2]]

slst = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0))
gs = it.groupby(slst, key=itemgetter(0))
res = [max(v, key=itemgetter(1)) for k,v in gs]
print(res)
```

produces

```
[[0, 2], [1, 4], [2, 6]]
```

Comment: I would use `itertools.groupby` if my solution was not `numpy` based. This is similar to `numpy.unique`

Comment: No worries. Glad to help others with a generic list

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the code segment below, which doesn't require any `imports`.

```
lst = [[2,6],[1,4],[0,1],[1,1],[2,3],[0,2]]

lst = sorted(lst) # Sort the list in increasing order.
lst = [lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if i+1 == len(lst) or lst[i+1][0] != lst[i][0]]
# Remove the elements with minimum 2nd element.

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 2], [1, 4], [2, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using a `dict`.

```
>>> [*dict(sorted(lst)).items()]
[(0, 2), (1, 4), (2, 6)]
```

It produces the pairs as tuples instead of lists, but you even accepted an answer that produces a numpy array. To get lists:

```
>>> [*map(list, dict(sorted(lst)).items())]
[[0, 2], [1, 4], [2, 6]]
```

These solutions work because the `dict` keeps the *last* value for each key, so if we sort first, then the last is the largest.

Comment: Nice approach! assuming CPython 3.6+ where dicts retain insertion order

Comment: @Chris_Rands Hmm. I switched from assuming CPython 3.6+ to assuming Python 3.7+ a while ago. It's been over two years :-). But I just checked, of the [five alternative implementations](https://www.python.org/download/alternatives/), only one appears to be at 3.7+. So I guess assuming Python 3.7+ doesn't *broaden* the user set but *narrows* it. Anyway, `sorted(dict(sorted(lst)).items())` for non-ordered dict.